# ANOVA with differring variable length

Tags: r

This code

```
x <- runif(100,1,99)
y <- runif(75,1,99)

aov(x ~ y)
```

Yields:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = x ~ y, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'y')
```

How can I run an ANOVA on variables with differing length?

I know this is asked in one form or another elsewhere, but never this simple. I feel this will help a lot of people trying to understand this concept.

Comment: try `lme` function from `nlme` package.

Comment: Unfortunately that gave a similar error: Error in model.frame.default(formula = ~y + x, data = <environment>, na.action = function (object,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')

Comment: why would they have different lengths? what assumptions about your data structure are you expecting the function to make?

Comment: Say I'm measuring tastiness of a food. I am comparing kids `x` and adults `y`. I interviewed more kids than I did adults.

Comment: If it's just two groups, `t.test(x=x, y=y)` would work.

Comment: in that case you would have data structured like this: `dd <- data.frame(value = c(x, y), group = rep(c('kid', 'adult'), c(length(x), length(y)))); summary(aov(value ~ group, dd))` or use `t.test` as @xilliam suggested

Comment: Perfect! Thank you both @xilliam and @rawr !
I tested the `data.frame()` method with an additonal z value as `z <- runif(88,1,99)` and it worked great! I ran a `TukeyHSD()` to confirm, too.

Answer (score -1):

`cbind` the vectors to make dataframe `df`.

```
x <- runif(100,1,99)
y <- runif(75,1,99)
n <- max(length(x), length(y))
length(x) <- n                      
length(y) <- n
df = cbind.data.frame(x, y)
```

Using `aov`,

```
aov(x ~ y, df)
Call:
   aov(formula = x ~ y, data = df)

Terms:
                       y Residuals
Sum of Squares   1944.48  62260.42
Deg. of Freedom        1        73

Residual standard error: 29.20415
Estimated effects may be unbalanced
25 observations deleted due to missingness
```

The last 25 obsersavation from of `x` are removed.

Data

```
structure(list(x = c(6.43782595498487, 65.0627944865264, 42.1409833072685, 
62.040753940586, 88.4672812684439, 68.0480401446112, 14.1146249887533, 
77.7449538419023, 63.8465470187366, 40.2226330521517, 40.9814450722188, 
66.2950497772545, 80.1532222172245, 19.8746005254798, 87.0539529765956, 
76.2959316247143, 39.9189768158831, 83.4147884747945, 41.4874139348976, 
81.7595121301711, 58.2948420289904, 69.5893019647337, 2.5656079207547, 
77.4886130276136, 89.7076172968373, 90.2972867144272, 57.0461049522273, 
48.6486821081489, 86.1181863597594, 6.84610393177718, 21.3447538255714, 
2.28933829534799, 75.2727376865223, 59.3039844627492, 8.0037846933119, 
94.0831268681213, 83.8350947140716, 84.1867832038552, 87.7109117829241, 
23.970201597549, 30.3296254063025, 87.7903240122832, 29.5167214921676, 
83.6757019879296, 24.3867463651113, 96.2189536481164, 78.1370823909529, 
14.8922761064023, 9.01647637411952, 30.1026425580494, 3.51024845382199, 
22.7971661840566, 78.0441143196076, 42.6963730677962, 87.2618790264241, 
68.5904617710039, 28.1216857754625, 34.4644382311963, 68.5020495592616, 
58.3388042054139, 36.4634911310859, 15.3161748088896, 44.9892013785429, 
16.158776440192, 61.3346478398889, 92.9719518530183, 20.412307985127, 
23.7431042515673, 22.8178576668724, 96.1691571301781, 44.4793640533462, 
25.016068413388, 9.35631886683404, 36.2819320964627, 16.8976151323877, 
67.8130137966946, 95.7082006833516, 6.74184384709224, 32.9904380538501, 
88.2270714226179, 49.7517288113013, 37.9916569939815, 77.0374707565643, 
24.4103356353007, 93.5636991830543, 94.4069208316505, 94.2138788020238, 
84.001830810681, 82.8615814042278, 13.9972089142539, 33.3026588936336, 
37.5912671987899, 37.6356486906298, 44.3349261954427, 83.3392078806646, 
45.1144304741174, 98.6915233819745, 11.7619684431702, 22.6129929595627, 
73.581154061947), y = c(83.4538785424083, 76.3444811031222, 61.289138940163, 
89.3607236105017, 77.2348131593317, 92.0743668745272, 2.18543963832781, 
47.7491315016523, 50.2828186992556, 42.5973479114473, 9.94040625775233, 
75.9307517521083, 5.13740657037124, 38.7119619767182, 47.7337393835187, 
12.7986594913527, 10.9862150717527, 35.8748660888523, 70.4895278979093, 
86.3194149998017, 39.4562139380723, 48.21358893672, 52.6149341971613, 
69.097069635056, 98.49209859455, 82.283846127335, 9.90846581803635, 
62.4972512507811, 62.3456196133047, 33.327835844364, 11.7582777966745, 
43.7686497499235, 56.1665550544858, 55.2842871476896, 91.7461385997012, 
56.5882844151929, 60.304024737794, 72.2035503163934, 60.3384374431334, 
8.06094888225198, 61.1845648423769, 39.1329287341796, 44.4383513685316, 
88.9414128032513, 20.9707002649084, 25.0101229283027, 56.1315523823723, 
33.0227301325649, 33.673303830903, 17.044317914173, 38.928902908694, 
78.4333872022107, 55.8677040948533, 76.0277622002177, 2.01517765969038, 
40.0475048287772, 54.2519091134891, 16.3640964687802, 75.4230435416102, 
45.1927063055336, 43.7694160495885, 69.695349747315, 91.5870576049201, 
14.7658055615611, 24.7752583785914, 53.5653891977854, 73.2316731559113, 
48.4703833381645, 68.0795386796817, 40.4994549499825, 79.0917908065021, 
40.1438044006936, 6.62396305054426, 41.1379012898542, 92.4432244333439, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))
```

Comment: `aov()` is exactly what I used as my example. Are you running another package or something?

Comment: No, the function `aov` is from `base` package

Comment: Then I have no idea why it's not working on my end. 'aov(x ~ y)' is what I am using, and is my original question.  Thanks any way!

Comment: I have revised the answer. Check again.

Comment: In the design mentioned in a comment above, x are kids and y are adults. By that guideline this is not the correct ANOVA model. You would need y to be a two-level factor (kids or adults). And then their numeric data would need to be converted to long format.